# Docker command/option to display or list the build context

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a command/option to display or list the context which is sent to the Docker daemon for building an image?

```
$ docker build -t "image-name"
Sending build context to Docker daemon 8.499 MB
...
```

Files and directories can be excluded from the build context by specifying patterns in a [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file. I guess what I'm looking for amounts to testing the `.dockerignore` in addition to any other niche rules Docker uses when determined the context.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The only way would be to add the current directory to an specific directory and list it.

Try building with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox

RUN mkdir /tmp/build/
# Add context to /tmp/build/
COPY . /tmp/build/
```

Build it with:

```
docker build -t test .
```

List all the files and directories in /tmp/build:

```
docker run --rm -it test find /tmp/build
```

Comment: You could do it in one step by including `RUN find /tmp/build` in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about Windows but WSL should have these GNU utilities installed.

Comment: You no longer need `RUN mkdir`

Comment: grabbing the one-liners approach from @whitone, but adapting to use the commands from this answer, for when buildx isn't available, we get: `printf 'FROM busybox\nCOPY . /tmp/build/\nRUN find /tmp/build' | docker build -f- .`

Comment: ...or if you want to see the size of the directories to help focus your search for large objects, you can use `printf 'FROM busybox\nCOPY . /tmp/build/\nRUN du -xhd1 /tmp/build' | docker build -f- .` (`du -xhd1` is the difference)

Answer (score 87):

Answers above are great, but there is a low-tech solution for most cases - `ncdu`. This utility will show pretty and interactive tree structure with sizes. It has an option that will take patterns from a file and exclude them from scan. So you can just do `ncdu -X .dockerignore`. You will get something like this:

[image]

This is pretty close to what you will get in your docker image. One caveat is thou if you add a dot directory (like `.yarn`) into an image, it will not show in `ncdu` output.

Comment: :)
I was looking for exactly this. 
This is an excellent answer. `ncdu` is something that was preinstalled.

Comment: A useful tool indeed, but it doesn't respect `.dockerignore`, which might be relevant given the question.

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrService You can tell it to use ignore file using `ncdu -X .dockerignore`

Comment: My mistake, I should have read more closely.  That's a neat trick!

Comment: It looks like the `-X` option doesn't support whitelist rules in `.dockerignore`

Comment: I don't see it respecting the blacklist items either (at least on the ncdu installed today from Homebrew).

Comment: This is not a good answer: `ncdu`'s `-X` option does not follow the docker's `.dockerignore` file syntax and specification

Comment: If the `.dockerignore` entries start with a slash, it won't work.

Comment: I always come here, install `ncdu`, read the comments, uninstall `ncdu`, then make a dummy container in some tmp folder somewhere...

Answer (score 34):

Starting with version 18.09, Docker has an option to export context data using [BuildKit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#buildkit) backend.

It's not enabled by default, so you need to set an environment variable `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` before invoking `docker build` command.

The following command can work also if you don't have any Dockerfile in current directory.

```
printf 'FROM scratch\nCOPY . /' | DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -f- -o context .
```

When you run multiple times remember to delete previous export with `rm -r context`.

You can also get context data as archive and then mount with `archivemount` command:

```
printf 'FROM scratch\nCOPY . /' | DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -f- -o- . > context.tar
mkdir context
archivemount context.tar context
```

With both methods, then you can explore the result with `ncdu context`.

Comment: nice, great answer ️(for people not wanting to install ncdu: `du -m context | sort -n`) ‍♂️️

Comment: Instead of redirecting to `context.tar` you also can just pipe the output to `tar -tv` so you don't have to deal with temporary files and directories.

Answer (score 14):

Updated answer: Since 2017, Docker has recommended to use `COPY` instead of `ADD` and with the comment from @tlrobinson, the simpler Dockerfile looks like so:

```
# debug and list the docker build context so that you can minimmize it
#
# usage:
#  docker build -f docker/context.Dockerfile -t test/buildcontext .
#
######################
FROM busybox

RUN mkdir /tmp/build/
# Add context to /tmp/build/
COPY . /tmp/build

# this last command outputs the list of files added to the build context:
RUN find /tmp/build/
```

Comment: I updated my answer to use `COPY` but the `find` in `RUN` doesn't have the flexibility of using the `find` command line options unless one uses ENTRYPOINT.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is to do the following (based on this [article](https://makeoptim.com/en/tool/docker-build-not-output)).

1. Tell Docker to use the old build kit. In PowerShell that is:

   $ENV:DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
2. Run Docker build so that it reports ALL the progress it's making:

   docker build --progress=plain BLAH

Given those two things you can then do something as simple as this in your Docker file:

```
RUN ls /app
```

And that will give you a list out of everything in the /app folder.

Comment: `RUN ls -R` is a better option, it's recursive, also run `docker build --no-cache` whilst tweaking your .gitignore file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that outputs the context tarball sent by `docker build` to the Docker daemon. You can examine it like `/path/to/script_below | tar -tv` for example.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from re import match
from socketserver import UnixStreamServer
from subprocess import Popen, DEVNULL
from sys import exit, stdout
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

class ContextDumper(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        # provide dummy client address for error reporting
        super().__init__(request, ('docker_context', 0), server)
        
    def do_HEAD(self):
        if self.path != '/_ping':
            self.send_error(404, '/_ping only')

    do_GET = do_HEAD

    def do_POST(self):
        if match(r'/v1\.\d+/build\?', self.path) is None:
            self.send_error(404, '/v1.X/build only')
            exit(1)
        total = 0
        while True:
            chunk_length = int(self.rfile.readline().strip(), 16)
            total += chunk_length
            chunk = self.rfile.read(chunk_length)
            stdout.buffer.write(chunk)
            self.rfile.readline()
            if chunk_length == 0:
                break
        padding = (512 - (total % 512)) % 512
        stdout.buffer.write(bytes(padding))
        exit(0)

with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    socket_path = tmpdir + '/docker_context.sock'
    fake_dockerd = UnixStreamServer(socket_path, ContextDumper)
    with Popen(['docker', f'--host=unix://{socket_path}', 'build', '--file=/dev/null', '.'],
               stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL) as builder:
        fake_dockerd.serve_forever()
```